# Start SIRI from iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I want to start siri programmably from my application.

There is any way to do it from my app like launch another app from package name ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I think you're looking for a uikit class analogous to `NSWorkspace` on the mac. There is no `NSWorkspace` api. That said, You can ask your application to open a URL who's scheme is handled by another application, but that won't work for siri unless siri has a scheme... maybe... `siri://`?